# How to make protection from repeated POST request processing in Django?

Tags: django, django-views

I'm almost done coding comment section in my app, but I realize, after user post comment and refresh the page, comment duplicates, but it's not what I want.

*views.py*

```
def post_detail(request, pk):
    template_name = 'books/post-detail.html'
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=pk)
    comments = book.comments.filter(active=True)
    new_comment = None
    # Comment posted
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():

            # Create Comment object but don't save to database yet
            new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            # Assign the current post to the comment
            new_comment.comment = book
            new_comment.username = request.user
            # Save the comment to the database
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()

    context = {'book': book,
                'comments': comments,
                'new_comment': new_comment,
                'comment_form': comment_form}

    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should follow Post/Redirect/Get (PRG) is a web development design pattern.

 inside if block of `POST` method if `form.is_valid()` returns `True` then you can redirect it to a new page otherwise render the same page.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

if request.method == 'POST':
    comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        # do some operation
        return redirect('/some/url/')
```

I've included some more information to rectify these kinds of mistakes in the future.

---

It is recommended to use ***class-based*** views in Django because they already handle these kinds of possibilities by providing methods such as `get_success_url` and attributes like `success_url`.
Detailed descriptions, with full methods and attributes, for each of Django's class-based generic views can be found here
http://ccbv.co.uk/

---

A little info on Post/Redirect/Get pattern

> **Post/Redirect/Get (PRG)** is a web development design pattern that lets
> the page shown after a form submission be reloaded, shared, or
> bookmarked without ill effects, such as submitting the form another
> time.
>
> When a web form is submitted to a server through an HTTP POST request,
> attempts to refresh the server response can cause the contents of the
> original POST to be resubmitted, possibly causing undesired results,
> such as a duplicate Object creation.
>
> To avoid this problem, many web developers use the PRG pattern,
> instead of returning a web page directly, the POST returns a redirect
> to another webpage. The HTTP 1.1 specification introduced the HTTP 303 response code to ensure that in this situation, browsers
> can safely refresh the server response without causing the initial
> POST request to be resubmitted.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get